# MySQL Querying Multiple Databases

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have multiple databases and I need to search for a value in a table and set it to NULL in all instances across all databases.

I know how to query individual databases after "USE 'DBName'" is called to select a particular database.

How do I loop all databases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [SHOW DATABASES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-databases.html) query to list all databases.

You don't need to `USE` the database to query its tables:

```
SELECT something FROM databasename.sometable
```